# Map jBPM REST response to Custom Object

Tags: web-services, jbpm

I am trying to parse response of rest https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1 to java object

```
class Response{
   long id;
   long userId;
   String title;
   String title;
}
```

I have mapped output variable *Result* to my global variable which is the object of custom class *Response* but it is not working out of the box.

Can anybody share a tutorial to achieve the same?

Comment: Store REST JSON response in process variable and use CustomWorkItemHandler to populate the java objects from json response.

Comment: Thanks Abhjit, Can you share some tutorial which helps me to write CustomWorkItemHandler using KIE Workbench.

Comment: To write customWorkItemHandler you have to implement org.kie.runtime.instance.WorkItemHandler interface. Go through https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.0/userguide/jBPMDomainSpecificProcesses.html for more details.

Comment: @YogeshPrajapati did you find the way to get response in custom object?

Comment: @Yogesh Prajapati if your problem is resolved, and still remember how, can you please explain or post a tutorial which can help, thanks